# how to use TextBox_Textchanged event with Regex for RequiredField Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

the textbox is associated with two RequiredFiled validators
also this textbox has TextChanged event.
I would like to allow first execute RequiredFiled validators then execute Textchanged event.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text,Regular_Expression))
    {
        Label2.Text = "from textChanged.";
    }
}

if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text,Regular_Expression))
```

here how to use regular expression with (`requiedfiled`, `regularExpression` controls)?

Can someone help me how to use RequiredFiled controls with text-box?
Actually, this script is for first validate required filed controls then execute textbox_Textchanged event. because the movement when the filled value in textbox, textbox change event is firing, so OOB(out of the box) control is not executing properly. to execute textbox required filed OOB control if the value is valid then `textbox_TextChanged` event should execute. just googled and find the
`Regex.IsMatch(textbox,RegularExepression)` but don't know how to use *Regular
Expressions*.

Comment: That's not ASP.NET Core. It looks like Web Forms, but it's hard to say. Check the tags on your question, and only add things that are relevant to your question.